# Comparison of receipes, written in German and in English

Tags: translation

How are the recipes written in German and in English different from each other? How is the writing style different? Which things are focused upon?

Comment: Huh? Speaking from experience, I'd say the difference between different writers, target audience and sources (blogs, cook books, magazines) is greater within each language than between languages per se. Cooking is a pretty international art.

Comment: But I'm not sure whether this question is within the scope of the site....

Comment: In old German recepies you usually se a lot of Konjunktiv I:  e.g: "man nehme zwei Eßlöffel Mehl.."

Comment: @Beta: Even the form is correctly stated, it may be helpful to mention the principle: It is  [Jussive mood](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jussiv).

Comment: no need to shout in the title

Comment: The differences between US-English recipe styles and German recipes and UK-English recipes *are different*. I don't think you can ask this based on language.

Answer (score 2):

Most important: the units! A German *Teelöffel* is a bit different from a North American *tea spoon* and when it comes to cups, ounces and °F, you have to consult a translation table like [this one](http://i0.wp.com/www.kochtrotz.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/umrechnungstabelle-cup-gr-ml-fahrenheit-celcius1.jpg?w=1191).

Comment: This is only partially true. (Modern) English recipes from the UK typically use metric weights where US sources tend to use volumetric measurements. Not to mention that there are differences between US, UK and AUS ounces, teaspoons etc.

Comment: Ah, this will change again soon. Metric system, such an evil idea only people from the continent could have come up with.

Comment: The metric system is much more accepted in the UK than it is on the "other continent", in my experience.